# send images from android studio to cpp

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, opencv

we work on a project in android studio. 
we try to send array of images from the java part to cpp.
then, we want to do some image processing actions and after that send the images back to the java side.

we represent every image as a matrix, and try to create array of matrices to send.
we try several differents way but couldn't find a way to do it right

```
Java:

static Mat[] imageMats = new Mat[3];

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageToUpload:
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESUALT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                break;
            case R.id.bottonUpload:

                start(imageMats, counter)

public native Mat start(Mat[] imageMats, int N);
```

```
Cpp:
Mat
Java_com_example_trycpp_MainActivity_start(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisobject, jobjectArray imageMats, jint N){
Data D;
D.source = vector<cv::Mat>(N)
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    D.sources[i] = (cv::Mat)(imageMats[i]); //error - _jobjectArray can't be cast to type "Mat": class "_jobjectAray" is not compatible with class "Mat"
}

}
```

we try also to use this way in the cpp part, but the app crashed. when we try to debug we saw a segmentation fault:

```
cpp:
jclass thisclass = env->GetObjectClass(thisobject);
jclass matclass = (env)->FindClass("org/opencv/core/Mat");

// Get methods and fields
jmethodID getPtrMethod = (env)->GetMethodID(matclass, "getNativeObjAddr", "()J");
jfieldID mrgbafieldid = env->GetFieldID(thisclass, "mRgba", "Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;");
jfieldID bufimgsfieldid = env->GetFieldID(thisclass, "bufImgs", "[Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;");

// Let's start: Get the fields
jobject mrgba = env->GetObjectField(thisobject, mrgbafieldid);
jobjectArray bufimgsArray = (jobjectArray)env->GetObjectField(thisobject, bufimgsfieldid);
D.sources[i] = *(cv::Mat*)env->CallLongMethod(env->GetObjectArrayElement(imageMats, i), getPtrMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass an image from Android part to native part, you can use **android/bitmap.h** from the NDK.

Here is an example which convert a bitmap into an Array2D (from dlib). I hope you can adapt it to your cases.

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "android/log.h"
#include "android/bitmap.h"

#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,    TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,     TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

void convertBitmapToArray2d(JNIEnv *env,
                            jobject bitmap,
                            dlib::array2d<dlib::bgr_pixel> &out) {
    AndroidBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;
    void *pixels;
    int state;

    if (0 > (state = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &bitmapInfo))) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed! error=%d", state);
        return;
    } else if (bitmapInfo.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not RGB_565!");
    }

    // Lock the bitmap for copying the pixels safely.
    if (0 > (state = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels))) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed! error=%d", state);
        return;
    }

    LOGI("info.width=%d, info.height=%d", bitmapInfo.width, bitmapInfo.height);
    out.set_size((long) bitmapInfo.height, (long) bitmapInfo.width);

    char *line = (char *) pixels;
    for (int h = 0; h < bitmapInfo.height; ++h) {
        for (int w = 0; w < bitmapInfo.width; ++w) {
            uint32_t *color = (uint32_t *) (line + 4 * w);

            out[h][w].red = (unsigned char) (0xFF & (*color));
            out[h][w].green = (unsigned char) (0xFF & ((*color) >> 8));
            out[h][w].blue = (unsigned char) (0xFF & ((*color) >> 16));
        }

        line = line + bitmapInfo.stride;
    }

    // Unlock the bitmap.
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, we didn't understand how to use your idea in our project.